# MS access : how to add 1 row between 2 rows?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an access database with these tables: 
- sequences: it describes the sequences of a movie : ex: boy kicking ball (1) , boy hitting ball(2), boy speaking(3) etc..

- movie: it is composed of sequences above.
  ex: 3 - 2 - 1 - 2

My problem is : how can I insert a new sequence because access always inserts it to the end.
ex: I would like to get (I would like to insert sequence 3 between 2 and 1)
3 - 2 - 3 - 1 - 2

and Access will give me 
3 - 2 - 1 - 2 - 3 (added to end)

Any clue ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of inserting data in a database is inconsequential, what is important is the order of retrieval which you manipulate by the [`ORDER BY`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/order-by-clause-HP001032258.aspx) substatement you provide your [`SELECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208930%28v=office.12%29.aspx) statement with.

So you'll need to identify the field by which you can order things, e.g. a sequence id and then order on that field. like thus

```
SELECT * FROM movie_sequences ORDER BY movie_sequence_id ASC;
```

Comment: that's very annoying: to insert a new record, I need to specify its number and also handle all records numbers.

Comment: @user300675 MS Access uses a relational database and relational databases do not have a fixed order. If you need a sequential file, you need a different application.

Comment: even when picking a nosql database you'll need to maintain order yourself by specifying between which 2 elements you want the element to come, so there always will be some bookkeeping.